# android.view.InflateException while using RTEditor

Tags: java, android, xml

I've been using RTEditor ([RTEditor Github](https://github.com/1gravity/Android-RTEditor)) in my application for almost a year and didn't have any problems with it. But after recent updated (Android Studio, Build tools, SDK Versions and etc.), my app crashes whenever I open the Activity with RTEditor.

I did some experiments and most probably the problem is with RTToolbar component. However when I am running their Demo application, it works fine.

StackTrace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.secomsoft.Saferoom, PID: 10147
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.secomsoft.Saferoom/com.secomsoft.Saferoom.Activity_CreateNote}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Binary XML file line #46: Binary XML file line #18: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Binary XML file line #46: Binary XML file line #18: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46: Binary XML file line #18: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Binary XML file line #18: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:765)
    at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:7034)
    at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:7216)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(LinearLayout.java:1926)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1824)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1823)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:989)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:854)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:994)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:854)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
    at com.secomsoft.Saferoom.Fragments.Fragment_CreateNote.onCreateView(Fragment_CreateNote.java:105)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2346)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureInflatedFragmentView(FragmentManager.java:1664)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1399)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1659)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1905)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3715)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:114)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:374)
    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:39)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:68)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:777)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at com.secomsoft.Saferoom.Activity_CreateNote.onCreate(Activity_CreateNote.java:22)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Activity Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.secomsoft.Saferoom.Activity_CreateNote">
<fragment android:name="com.secomsoft.Saferoom.Fragments.Fragment_CreateNote"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentNotebooks"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Fragment Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.secomsoft.Saferoom.Activity_CreateNote">

<!-- Toolbar  -->
<include layout="@layout/toolbar_start"/>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/marginContainer"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_below="@+id/saferoomBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:gravity="center"
        style="@style/editText"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/HINT_NOTE_TITLE"
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtService"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/cog"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/android_next"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:text="Select service"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutCreateNote"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtService"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/rte_toolbar_container"
            layout="@layout/rte_toolbar" />
        <com.onegravity.rteditor.RTEditText
            android:id="@+id/txtContent"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@null"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoEnterAction"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/linearlayout_border"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/fileLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="left" android:padding="15dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/file_doc"
            android:id="@+id/fileIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:id="@+id/fileText"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Amazon Web Services.pdf\nSize: 519 kb"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState){


    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_createnote, container, false);
    delegate = this;

    // Checking if tablet
    isTablet = SaferoomHelper.IsTablet(getActivity());

    // Disabling unnecessary buttons
    view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_superscript).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_subscript).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_font).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_bgcolor).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_inc_indent).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_dec_indent).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_image).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_image_capture).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_clear).setVisibility(View.GONE);

    // Initializing top toolbar
    toolbar = (Toolbar)view.findViewById(R.id.saferoomBar);
    toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.TITLE_NOTE_CREATENEW));
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_createnote);
    toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    if (!isTablet){
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.android_back_white);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                backClickedListener.OnBackClicked();
            }
        });
    }
    fileLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.fileLayout);

    // Setting padding
    SaferoomHelper.setMargin(view,SaferoomHelper.IsTablet(getActivity()));

    // create RTManager
    RTApi rtApi = new RTApi(getActivity(), new RTProxyImpl(getActivity()), new RTMediaFactoryImpl(getActivity(), true));
    rtManager = new RTManager(rtApi, savedInstanceState);

    // register toolbar
    ViewGroup toolbarContainer = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.rte_toolbar_container);
    RTToolbar rtToolbar = (RTToolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.rte_toolbar);
    if (rtToolbar != null) {rtManager.registerToolbar(toolbarContainer, rtToolbar);}

    // register editor & set text
    txtContent = (RTEditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtContent);
    rtManager.registerEditor(txtContent, true);
    txtContent.setRichTextEditing(true, " ");

    // Initializing UI elements
    txtService = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtService);
    txtService.setOnClickListener(this);
    txtTitle = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

    // Setting TextWatcher
    txtContent.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            difference = txtContent.getSelectionStart();
            if (i2 == 0) {
                removeSpans = txtContent.getEditableText().getSpans(0, txtContent.length(), ImageSpan.class);
                for (ImageSpan span : removeSpans) {
                    if ((difference >= txtContent.getEditableText().getSpanStart(span))
                            &&
                            (difference <= txtContent.getEditableText().getSpanEnd(span))) {
                        txtContent.getText().replace(txtContent.getEditableText().getSpanStart(span),
                                txtContent.getEditableText().getSpanEnd(span), "");
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });


    // Checking if the Share Files function has been called
    fileLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            intent = getActivity().getIntent();
            if ((Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(intent.getAction()) ||
                    Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(intent.getAction())) && intent.getType() != null) {
                if (Config.supportedFiles.contains(intent.getType())) {
                    if (intent.getData() != null) {
                        SaferoomHelper.AddFile(getActivity(), txtContent, intent.getData(), isTablet);
                    } else if (intent.getClipData() != null) {
                        ClipData clipData = intent.getClipData();
                        for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                            try {
                                Uri uri = clipData.getItemAt(i).getUri();
                                SaferoomHelper.AddFile(getActivity(), txtContent, uri, isTablet);
                            } catch (Exception ex) {

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    initValues();
    return view;
}
```

Comment: The problem is in one of the `<include>`d layouts. Apparently, around line 18, you have something inside a `<LinearLayout>`, and that something is missing a `layout_width`.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for reply. I tried to take a look at their source code, but apparently my Android skills are not enough to verify. Interesting thing is that when run their demo and use the <include> tag, it's working fine.

Comment: Well, they're setting the `layout_width`s and `layout_height`s for a bunch of stuff in `<style>`s, instead of directly on the `<View>`s in the layout. This has always been kinda shaky, judging from others' posts I've seen. I seem to recall playing around with it once, but I don't recall the outcome. I would think it should work, technically, but I never do it, myself. If you want, you could try copying [that layout](https://github.com/1gravity/Android-RTEditor/blob/master/RTEditor-Toolbar/src/main/res/layout/rte_toolbar.xml) into your project, and explicitly settings those attributes on each.